# After using "overflow-y: scroll", the stacking order of the boxes DIV is changed

Tags: css, overflow

[image: image1]

I need to implement the green box on top of the purple box, and the purple box needs to have a scroll effect. But when I used **overflow-y: scroll**, the green box ran behind the purple box.

[image: image2]

My code as below:

```
.box_middle{

    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

.class1{

    background-color: blueviolet;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.class2{

    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-top: -550px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

[image: image3]

Comment: can you add the html part also ? with image, its hard to reproduce snippet

Answer (score 0):

to bring class2 on top of class1.
use position as absolute

```
.class2{

    background-color: aquamarine;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: -550px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: TKS. The requirement is to achieve without using POSITION ：-（